# Python Downloading files is working, but the downloaded files are not showing

Tags: python, python-3.x, download, urllib

I've got this simple script :

```
listVideos = ['url1', 'url2', ...]
print ("Downloading files...")

for url in listVideos:
        print ("Downloading : "+url)
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, '/videos')
```

My goal, as you probably guessed, is to download the files from the urls of the `listVideos`in the folder named `videos`. When running my script, no error are printed and everything seems to work perfectly. 
Between each `print ("Downloading : "+url)`, there is some delay which I assume is because of the downloading. So everything seems to work fine.

But when the script is over, there is no files in my `videos`folder, and I can't figure out why.

For intel, my `videos`folder is at the same location as my script.

Comment: Where are you looking for your videos folder? You have an absolute path `/videos`, not a relative path.

Comment: `'/videos'`... are you trying to save data in a folder inside your root? if the folder is a local subfolder remove the `/`before the folder name

Comment: I've also tried `'videos'` instead of `'/videos'`but then it gives me this error : `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'videos'`. Weird, because when creating my folder, i do the following : `os.chmod('videos', 0o777)`

Comment: The permission error is rather clear though. Where exactly are you trying to create that folder? Try again with a path to a folder in you user's home directory

Comment: @GPhilo `if not os.path.exists("videos"):
    os.makedirs("videos")
    os.chmod('videos', 0o777)
    print ("Dossier créé")` The folder is created in the same folder as the script : `myfolder/videos/ and myfolder/myScript.py`

Comment: Please try with a different folder location and see if that works

Comment: @GPhilo I tried without specificing any folder : `urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, '')` I don't have error, but the files are not showing neither

Comment: so what is your current working directory when you try to create the directory? Test with `print(os.getcwd())`; relative paths are created based of that. It's best to use an absolute path to your expected location, using the *full path*.

Comment: Moreover, what is the returned value of your `urlretrieve` function? It [returns  tuple with the filename of the downloaded file](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/urllib.request.html#legacy-interface)

Comment: @GPhilo Honestly I have no clue how to check the returned value of the `urlretrieve`

Comment: ... `my_returned_tuple = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, '')` followed by `print(my_returned_tuple)`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters `G:\1 -Infographie\1 -Travaux\Professionnel\Python\dlVideos.py `

Comment: @GPhilo `('C:\\Users\\JSHO~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmptgyojh66', <http.client.HTTPMessage object at 0x041E7F70>)`

Comment: `'C:\\Users\\JSHO~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmptgyojh66'` is your video file. Copy to wherever you need it with `os.rename()` or `shutil.move()`

Comment: Tho I noticed that if I do `urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'video.mp4')` it does actually create a file `video.mp4`. As i'm downloading a list of files, I believe I should get the file name when downloading it so I could past it as an argument like `urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, FileName)`. Is there anyway to get this name ?

Comment: @Ezhno: That's a little unexpected; did you name your folder `dlVideos.py` there? And what is the full path of the directory where you *expected* to get your videos downloaded? When your script succeeds, it is writing to `G:\videos` I think, and when your code fails with a relative path, that's in `G:\1 -Infographie\1 -Travaux\Professionnel\Python\dlVideos.py\videos`.

Comment: @Ezhno: ah, no, `urlretrieve()` does not take a folder. It only takes a single filename. You'd have to use `os.path.join(path_to_folder, new_filename)` as the second argument.

Comment: @MartijnPieters My script is named `dlVideos.py` and my download folder is named `videos` as you know already. Both are in the folder `python` that is located in, let's say, `G:\`

Comment: @Ezhno: `os.getcwd()` produces the current working *directory*. If that returns a path with `dlVideos.py` at the end, then that's unexpected, and that's why I asked. If you gave me the path of the script instead, then that's not what I asked.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I noticed it does indeed only take a filename. That's why I would like to get the name of the file that i'm downloading so that I could paste it as the filename argument of `urlretrieve()`, so that it would create my file with the correct name. (I need to keep the files name)

Comment: @MartijnPieters This is indeed what os.getcwd() returned. Maybe it is because i'm working with the IDLE module on window ?

Comment: @Ezhno: [How to extract a filename from a URL & append a word to it?](//stackoverflow.com/q/18727347) applies then.